# Seven segment project using atmega16 and external interrupts

Tags: c, avr

I have been working on a simple project on AVR microcontroller atmega16 on proteus simulation.

The project is:
When I push the push button it increments the seven segment to number 9 and after that if the we pushed the button again it overflows and return again to 0.
When I change the (flag=1;) position at while loop code it gives me different outputs and by this I mean when I push the push button it didn't response after the pushing.
It may require another pushing to the button to increment the seven segment [proteus simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU73z.png)

The only code that worked properly is when set `flag=1;` before exiting (the second if and else conditions)

So my question is what actually happened when I change the `flag=1;` statement position at the code.

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<avr/interrupt.h>
char flag=1;
char num=0;
void INT2_Init(void){
    DDRB&=~(1<<2);
    SREG|=(1<<7);
    GICR|=(1<<INT2);
    MCUCSR|=(1<<ISC2);
}
ISR(INT2_vect){
    flag=0;
    GIFR|=(1<<INTF2);
}

int main(void){
    DDRC=0x0f;
    PORTC=0;
    DDRB&=~(1<<2);
    INT2_Init();
    while(1){
        if(flag==0){
            if(num>8){
                num=0;
                PORTC=(PORTC&0xf0)|num;
            }
            else{
                num++;
                PORTC=(PORTC&0xf0)|num;
            }
        }
        flag=1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some variable changes in main code and interrupt, you have to mark it `volatile`. Otherwise, the compiler may decide to cache variable value and omit its reading inside a loop.

`volatile char flag=1;`

Second, pay attention when and where your flag variables are changed. E.g.:

```
    while(1){
        // at this point flag is 0, comparison failed
        if(flag==0) {
          ...
        }
// Interrupt happens here, changing flag to 0
// Then flag is immediately reset, thus flag change is missed in the loop
        flag=1; 
    }
```

Instead consider to use such a pattern:

```
    while (1) {
         cli(); // disabling interrupts ensuring no interrupt happens inside 
         if (flag==0) {
           ...
         }
         flag = 1;
         sei(); // re-enable interrupts
    }
```

or, in this case, it can be simpler

```
    while (1) {
         if (flag==0) {
             flag = 1; // Reset flag only if it set, right after comparison
             ...
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear to me what you are asking. Do you just struggle to understand the code? Do my comments help?

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<avr/interrupt.h>
char flag=1;
char num=0;

void INT2_Init(void){
    DDRB&=~(1<<2);
    SREG|=(1<<7);
    GICR|=(1<<INT2);
    MCUCSR|=(1<<ISC2);
}

// sets flag to 0 on external interrupt (button press)
ISR(INT2_vect){
    flag=0;
    GIFR|=(1<<INTF2);
}

int main(void){
    DDRC=0x0f;
    PORTC=0;
    DDRB&=~(1<<2);
    INT2_Init();

    while(1){
        // if flag was set to 0 in external interrupt -> increment (or overflow) number on segment display
        if(flag==0){
            if(num>8){
                num=0;
                PORTC=(PORTC&0xf0)|num;
            }
            else{
                num++;
                PORTC=(PORTC&0xf0)|num;
            }
        }
        // reset the flag to 1 to prevent num from being incremented continuously
        flag=1;
    }
}
```

I would suggest to move `flag=1;` inside the `if` to make the intent clear that the statement should only execute once with every button press.

```
    while(1) {
        // if flag was set to 0 in external interrupt -> increment (or overflow) number on segment display
        if(flag==0){
          // reset the flag to 1 to prevent num from being incremented continuously
          flag=1;

            if(num>8){
                num=0;
                PORTC=(PORTC&0xf0)|num;
            }
            else{
                num++;
                PORTC=(PORTC&0xf0)|num;
            }
        }
    }
```

It is also advisable to use self descriptive variable names. Like `buttonWasPressed` instead of `flag` for example. That makes code like that much easier to read.